# What to do when your Linux Mint 13 screen locks up with Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

It's not all that uncommon for the display to lock up or just get weird on Linux Mint 13 with Cinnamon and 3 displays.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do the following:

1. Hit Alt-F2, then type 'r' and hit Enter. Sometimes that fixes the problem.
2. Otherwise, Cinnamon will restart if you kill it (like the Mac Finder).

   - hit Ctrl-Alt-F1, and login to a terminal. Then run this command:
     killall -9 cinnamon
   - hit Ctrl-Alt-F8, to get back to X
   - if you have multiple displays, you'll find windows stretching across displays. Do step #1 of Alt-F2 'r', and that problem should be fixed.

I found that running cinnamon --replace does not seem to work well.